# Let $G$ be a group and $x\in G$. Suppose that $\exists n\geq 1$ such that $x^n=e$. Show that $\exists m\geq 1$, such that $x^{-1}=x^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question has  already a answer in mathstackexchange but i have different question.

So the question is: Let $G$ be a group and $x\in G$. Suppose that there is an integer $n\geq 1$ such that $x^n=e$. Show that there is an integer $m\geq 1$, such that $x^{-1}=x^m$

Now we have $x^px^q=x^{p+q}$ $\forall$ $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$

So if we take, $p=n,q=-1$ then  as $x^n=e$
we have $x^{-1}=x^{n-1}$

But if we take $m=n-1$ then as $n\geq 1$ so $m=n-1\geq 0$. So we are getting $m\geq 0$ instead of $m\geq 1$ so what to do now?

Well if we take $m=0$, then $x=e$, thus if we assume $x \neq e$ then we have $m\geq 1$ but according to question x can be e. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $x^n=e$ is equivalent to $x^{n-1}=x^{-1}$ by multiplying with $x^{-1}\in G$. It doesn't matter that $n-1\ge 0$ could be zero. Then $x^{-1}=x^0=e$, the neutral element.

Comment: You seem to be worrying only about the case $x=e$. In that case we can take $m=127$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x = e$, then $x^{-1} = e^{-1} = e = e^{10} = x^{10}$. Since $e$ is the neutral element, it is its own inverse and you can multiply it with itself as often as you wish and it stays $e$. Hence $e^{-1} = e^m$ is true for any integer $m$, in particular any $m \geq 1$. (I took $10$ as an example in the beginnin of the answer.) You are right, if you want to have $m \geq 1$, you need to take $x = e$ as a special case. But it is a trivial special case.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Uups. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No need to differentiate cases: if $x^n=e$, then $x^{2n}=e$ and you have $2n\ge2$, so
$$
x^{2n-1}=x^{-1}
$$
with $2n-1\ge1$.

But you can easily eliminate the case $n=1$ by noting that, in this case, $x=e$ and clearly $e^1=e^{-1}$.